# CA Erwin 9.0 - Is there a way to add a suffix or prefix to all the columns in a single table

Tags: data-modeling, erwin

CA Erwin 9.0 - Is there a way to add a suffix or prefix to all the columns in a single table  in Erwin .

I have tried using the "Model Naming Option" , however it renames all the attributes in all the entities .

This is for my logical model .